# webflow 1.0.x in depth

Tags: spring, spring-webflow

After debugging an issue which was found to be related to webflow 1.0.x configuration, I am trying to find a detailed documentation/discussion of what are webflow 1.0.x repository types, and related configuration parameters (spring webflow documentation is very terse on this, and one wonders why). Can anyone help me with this?

Comment: maybe the reference documentation helps you http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/1.0.x/reference/

Comment: I look for something less terse, and I wish to avoid to dig into the source code.

Comment: found a solution? let us know!

Answer (score 1):

you're only possibilities are:

- [Reference Guide](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/1.0.x/reference/index.html)
- [API (JavaDoc)](http://static.springsource.org/spring-webflow/docs/1.0.x/api/index.html)
- [Jira](https://jira.springsource.org/browse/SWF)
- And digging in the depth of the source-code